Help with AM-GM ineq
We have $abc=1$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+ac+bc$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.
Since $a^2, b^2, c^2\in\mathbb{R^+}$, we can use AM-GM inequality to get
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq3\cdot\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}=3$$
Thus, $$a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+ac+bc\geq3=3\cdot\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$$
Can we conclude that $ab, ac, bc\in\mathbb{R^+}$ since $ab+ac+bc\geq3\cdot\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}$ fulfills the AM-GM inequality?
I'm currently doing a high school olympiad question, and i got confused with this in the middle of the solution. I was trying to find all $(a,b,c)$ that fulfills $abc=1$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+ac+bc$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

This is a basic question.
We have $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca\Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 =0 \Leftrightarrow a=b=c $ . Since $abc=1$, so $a=b=c=1$.
Notice, we can prove $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$.

Why "Since =1, so ===1" if a, b, c not natural numbers but in R?

I have proven $a=b=c$.
